# Scraping javascript content using Scrapy and Splash

Tags: python, scrapy, scrapy-splash

I am scraping this link using scrapy and splash : [job search](https://manulife.taleo.net/careersection/external_global/jobsearch.ftl?lang=en&location=1038)

But I am not able extract the data.

My code :

```
 import scrapy
 from scrapy_splash import SplashRequest
 class ManuPySpider(scrapy.Spider):
   name = 'manulife'


   def start_requests(self):
    yield SplashRequest(
        url = 'https://manulife.taleo.net/careersection/external_global/jobsearch.ftl?lang=en&location=1038',
        callback=self.parse,
    )


   def parse(self, response):
    yield{
        'demo' : response.css('div.absolute > span > a::text').extract()
    }
```

Setting.py :

```
BOT_NAME = 'manulife'

SPIDER_MODULES = ['manulife.spiders']
NEWSPIDER_MODULE = 'manulife.spiders'




DOWNLOADER_MIDDLEWARES = {
 'scrapy_splash.SplashCookiesMiddleware': 723,
 'scrapy_splash.SplashMiddleware': 725,
 'scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.httpcompression.HttpCompressionMiddleware': 
  810,
  }

SPLASH_URL = 'http://192.168.99.100:8050'

SPIDER_MIDDLEWARES = {
'scrapy_splash.SplashDeduplicateArgsMiddleware': 100,
}

DUPEFILTER_CLASS = 'scrapy_splash.SplashAwareDupeFilter'
HTTPCACHE_STORAGE = 'scrapy_splash.SplashAwareFSCacheStorage'


# Obey robots.txt rules
ROBOTSTXT_OBEY = True
```

I have checked my splash is up and running. What might be the problem with it.

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When I tried to render the page using default settings via Splash console (on `8050` port), it didn't contain the required data (i.e. search result table was empty). But once I increased the `wait` parameter, it worked. So try to increase the parameter:

```
yield SplashRequest(
    url = 'https://manulife.taleo.net/careersection/external_global/jobsearch.ftl?lang=en&location=1038',
    callback=self.parse, args={'wait': 5}
)
```

Comment: Great that worked for me. BTW what is the reason behind it? Is the website rendering the data slow?

Comment: [splash:wait](http://splash.readthedocs.io/en/stable/scripting-ref.html#splash-wait), which is set by `wait` parameter, allows rendering engine to process the page after it was loaded. That's sometimes needed in case content is being updated by e.g. JavaScript, which takes some time.